# Tokenize array of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, string-formatting

I have a column A that contains triplets of numbers in the format `X,Y,Z` where either X, Y and Z can range from 0..100. I want to split these triplets into separate columns so that an example would look like this:

```
|    A     | B  | C  |  D |
| 30,10,60 | 30 | 10 | 60 |
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried the Text to Columns feature (Data tab) using the Delimited option with comma as the delimiter?

Comment: Well I'll be damned! I did not know about that feature, it is exactly what I wanted thank you very much! Post this as an answer and I will mark it as such and give an upvote :)

Comment: Done. And you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Text to Columns feature (Data tab) using the Delimited option with comma as the delimiter?

Regards